# How can I reference two HTML files that use jquery in an html index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an index page for two HTML files that use jquery.
Here's a breakdown of the files:

- **Emps1,Emps2:** Two HTML tables that have empty tables
- **TabA_stats,TabB_stats**: An independent js file for each HTML file to populate the
  tables with data from .csv files
- **Tab_A_4-1-2014,Tab_B_4-1-2014**: Two HTML files that use the empty tables HTML files, and JS to make a filled out table
- **CSV_A_4-1-2014,CSV_B_4-1-2014**: two CSV files that contain data
- **Index**: This is where I'm trying to reference both of **Tab1, Tab2**

So I've tried to reference both of **Tab_A_4-1-2014 and Tab_B_4-1-2014** in **Index**, so when I click a link, either **Tab_A_4-1-2014 or Tab_B_4-1-2014** will run on the same page.

So basically, the javascript looks at the name of the HTML tables (**Tab_A_04-01-2014 and Tab_B_04-01-2014**) and looks for CSV files with the corresponding dates to fill the tables out with the data (**CSV_A_4-1-2014,CSV_B_4-1-2014**)

My problem is that the two tables won't populate, and when I debug I think the problem is when the JS trys to grab the file name:

**TabA_stats** (just the header where i think i have a problem:

```
var path_data = location.pathname.split("_");
var date_info = path_data[2].split(".");
var log_date = date_info[0];
$("#logdate").text(log_date);
```

So meaning, the js files are seeing that file name is just index.html, and can't find a csv to fill it out with.

How can I solve this? and please explain as much as you can, since I'm only a week into JS and Jquery

EDIT:

**Tab1_4-1-2014** (for now im only working with the first table):

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tab1_style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="tabA_stats_div">       
      </div>

      <script>    
       //load HTML layout, tables into div "ess_stats_div" 
       $('#tabA_stats_div').load("tabA_stats.html");

       //load js file "tabA_stats.js" and execute
       $.getScript('tabA_stats.js');           
      </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**index** (i only have tab1) so far:

```
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ess_style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="topBar">
    <a href ="#" id="load_home"> Tab1 </a>
</div>
<div id ="content">        
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("Tab_A_04-01-2014.html");
    });
});
</script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This looks overcomplicated when I suspect the actual problem you are trying to solve is much simpler. Can you explain *the problem you are trying to solve* as well? Failing that please provide a sample of each HTML file for reference.

Comment: The question is quite confusing. Why do you have tables in separate HTML files?

Comment: Have a look into `iframe` tags. You can load external html files into them and then target the iframe contents and switch the source when you want the other html file.

Comment: @Starscream1984 the "emps1, emps2" HTML files are basically just a frame, you know like with just the table headers and rows. then the other "tab1,tab2" HTML tables use the "definition" HTML file and use the js to populate it into "tab1,tab2"

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yeah, I'm just trying to get a very simple index page that links to both "tab1 and tab2". when i click on one, it should show up on the index page, when i click on the other the first table should go away and the other should show up. My problem is that the only empty tables are showing up, because the javascript is looking at the index filename for some reason, and can't find a corrosponding .csv file

Comment: You will need to show more code. It sounds like you are dynamically loading the other pages into your index page. If so, the location URL will not change. Can you show your code as well?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, exactly ... and I just put up the code, hope its enough.

Comment: @foobarbecue more minimal than the recent edit?

Comment: @user3485257, we need to know the value of location.pathname . Put alert(location.pathname) before it and let us know what you get.

Comment: @foobarbecue I get "C:/Users/Desktop/Project%201/LOGSTATS/TabA_04-01-2014.html"

Comment: @gaynorvader so when I switch the source, does that mean it will also switch the path that the .js file will see?

Comment: @DaPhunk there's no need to switch the path the js file sees as you are targeting whatever html file loaded into the `iframe`. So when you change the source, you change the child elements of the `iframe`. As an example if you have 2 html files with an element with `id="text"` and the name of the html files (i.e. htmlA, htmlB) then when you use `getElementById('text').innerHtml()` you will see whatever html is currently loaded into the `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is zero-indexed. So, if you're looking for the part after the first underscore, you want

```
var date_info = path_data[1].split(".");
```

instead of

```
var date_info = path_data[2].split(".");
```

Comment: Actually I made a mistake while writing filenames here, it should be "Tab_A_4-1-2014,Tab_B_4-1-2014" so I do need the part after the second underscore.

Comment: So was your pathname.location not "C:/Users/Desktop/Project%201/LOGSTATS/TabA_04-01-2014.html" as you posted in the comment above?? That is the value that matters...

Comment: yeah it was actually "C:/Users/Desktop/Project%201/LOGSTATS/Tab_A_04-01-2014.html"

Comment: but in index.html, when i click on the ref to Tab_A_04-01-2014.html,  i did alert(pathname.location) and got "C:/.../index.html", so that's what i'm trying to figure out, I want it to be "C:/.../Tab_A_04-01-2014" instead.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you're experiencing is expected; the JavaScript `location` object contains information about **the current URL** ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)). So if this script (claimed to be part of TabA_stats) is run on `index.html` in the root directory, then `location.pathname` will return exactly that (`index.html`), assuming it's run on a server instead of locally viewed since your full directory path will be included in the latter case.

Now, let's talk about how your browser *actually works*. When you visit your home page (`index.html`), your browser sends a request to your **server** for the file `index.html`. When the HTML file is sent back to your browser, it begins reading through it, picking out pieces that it doesn't have (i.e. JavaScript files, images, etc.) and builds requests for those items as well, which it sends back to your **server**. Your browser also renders the things it can process and loads in the remaining resources as they arrive (this exact process is different per browser, but the general idea is the same).

Let's stop right there; what do you have now? You have your fully loaded [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), or Document Object Model. At the core, this is essentially a tree of all the HTML elements on the page. Has any JavaScript code been run yet? Probably; but by using something like `$(document).ready();` we can postpone our jQuery code (which most often accesses/manipulates the DOM) to run after the DOM is completely loaded. Remember, JavaScript is the language; jQuery is just a library or extension on JS.

Aside from the problem I outlined in the first paragraph, your edits to your post have made it clear to me that you have way too many layers of separation. It almost *feels* like you are attempting to apply Object-Oriented practices to web development. Let's ditch the idea that each table is a separate "object" and so it has to have its own HTML file. Instead, let's compile everything into the least amount of resources possible to make this load as fast as possible to your users.

You can reduce your structure down to 1 HTML file and 1 JS file (I'm assuming your CSV files are dumps from somewhere and are subject to change, so we'll leave those alone). Your `index.html` file should contain **both** tabs, which each contain the HTML elements required for each table. Everything should be defined as HTML in your `index.html` **unless** there is dynamic data that physically can't be sent with the request (in your case, your CSV files). So we can leave it up to jQuery's AJAX feature to load in the data from the CSV files after our DOM is loaded.

**In short:** You have a lot of reading to do **BEFORE** you continue. I suggest you don't continue with your current structure and way of thinking about this project. Start with 1 HTML file and 1 JS file; do as much as you can with static HTML before using JS to load your dynamic data. Post a specific question once you have the concepts down and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Is there anyway I can specify a path for the Tab_A_04-01-2014 in the index file so I can make the JS work?

Comment: Any way you can specify a path? Uh, lots of ways. One is to hard code it as a string. It seems what you want is to use javascript to get the file path on disk of the current page. That is impossible -- that information is not available to the web browser for security and other reasons. A web server serves your files; it doesn't just expose them. Nate has done an excellent job of writing you an introduction to the things you need to learn. Please accept his answer and go learn them.